I have problem with model.fit() function, with its arguments
I'm trying to train a CNN model with images in size 256*256, I will be using this model for my convolutional neural network that will be used to work on old art images.
I also have different number of images in these files (in the train dataset and val dataset)
this is the code:
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

model = Sequential()

# Add layers
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
#filtesr: (int) the number of filters in the convolution.

#kernel_size: (int or two intager numbers) specifying the size of onvolution window.
#activation: activation function, if None no actevation function done.
#input_shape: if data_format='channel_last' A 4D tensor with shape: (batch_size, height, width, channels)


model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#pooling_size: (int or two intager nubmbers) factors by which to downscale (dim1, dim2).

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
#Flattens the input. Does not affect the batch size.


model.add(Dense(units=256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))  # Adjust output units for the number of classes

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#optimizer: String (name of optimizer) or optimizer instance.
#loss: (string) name of loss function 
#metrics: List of metrics to be evaluated by the model during training and testing.


# Define paths
train_dir = 'C:/Users/M-LY/Desktop/dataset/train'
val_dir = 'C:/Users/M-LY/Desktop/dataset/val'

# Create ImageDataGenerator for data augmentation and rescaling
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  # Normalize pixel values to [0, 1]


#image data genorator for train
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Load images from directories
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,      #path to train data
    target_size=(256, 256),  # Resize images to match model input
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')  # Use 'categorical' for multi-class classification, and 'binary' for only two classes classification

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')


# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size, #train_generator.sample=440 #13
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=val_generator.samples // val_generator.batch_size,    #6
    epochs=50)  # Adjust the number of epochs as needed
test_dir = 'C:/Users/M-LY/Desktop/dataset/test'

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_generator)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")


model.save('cnn_model.h5')  # Save model to file



but it keep giving this error :
Found 440 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 211 images belonging to 2 classes.
C:\Users\M-LY\bs\gradbb\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\trainers\data_adapters\py_dataset_adapter.py:121: UserWarning: Your `PyDataset` class should call `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in its constructor. `**kwargs` can include `workers`, `use_multiprocessing`, `max_queue_size`. Do not pass these arguments to `fit()`, as they will be ignored.
  self._warn_if_super_not_called()
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\M-LY\bs\gradbb\network.py", line 64, in <module>
    history = model.fit(
              ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\M-LY\bs\gradbb\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\M-LY\bs\gradbb\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\nn.py", line 623, in categorical_crossentropy
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Arguments `target` and `output` must have the same rank (ndim). Received: target.shape=(None,), output.shape=(None, 10)

I do not know what is the problem with the function or is it in a different part of the code. I'm new to tensorflow and I need it for my graduation project. HELP

The error occurs because the loss='categorical_crossentropy' expects one-hot encoded labels (for multi-class classification), but your data generator is producing integer labels (not one-hot encoded). Here's how to fix the issue step by step:
Fix Explanation
Output Layer Adjustment:
Your output layer is configured for 10 classes:
python code
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))

This is correct if your dataset contains 10 classes. If you have a different number of classes, ensure the output units match.
Change class_mode to categorical:
Since your output layer uses softmax and expects one-hot encoded labels, update the class_mode in the data generators:
python code
class_mode='categorical'

Check the Number of Classes:
Ensure the train and val directories have subfolders matching the number of classes you’re working with.
Updated Code
Replace your data generators with the following:
python code
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'  # Use 'categorical' for multi-class classification
)

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'
)

Key Adjustments
Number of Units in the Output Layer:
If you have more or fewer classes, adjust the output layer accordingly:
python code
model.add(Dense(units=<number_of_classes>, activation='softmax'))

Loss Function:
If you’re working with one-hot encoded labels, keep:
python code
loss='categorical_crossentropy'

If you switch to integer labels, use:
python code
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'

In this case, set class_mode='binary' or class_mode='sparse' in the data generators.
Debugging Tips
Verify Classes:
Check the folders in train and val directories:
Each subfolder corresponds to a class.
The total number of subfolders should match the number of output units in the Dense layer.
Print Class Indices:
After creating the generator, print the class indices:
python code
print(train_generator.class_indices)

Sanity Check for Labels:
Before training, verify the shape of the labels produced by the generator:
python code
for data_batch, labels_batch in train_generator:
    print(f"Data batch shape: {data_batch.shape}")
    print(f"Labels batch shape: {labels_batch.shape}")
    break

Final Notes
Once these adjustments are in place, your model should work without the rank mismatch error.
If you’re still facing issues or have more questions about your CNN architecture, feel free to ask. Good luck with your graduation project! 
